# any idea how to save a data string of int which is more than the max length into sql database?

Tags: python, sql, ponyorm

```
 IBAN = Required(str)
    Credit_Card_number = Required(int)
    CV2 = Required(int)
```

```
"credit_card_number": "2221597849919620",
```

```
with db_session:
    with open('user_data.json') as f:
```

```
 for i in data:
            Card(FirstName=i['firstName'], LastName=i['lastName'], Age=i['age'], IBAN=i['iban'], Credit_Card_number=i['credit_card_number'],.......
```

ValueError: Value 2221597849919620 of attr Card.Credit_Card_number is greater than the maximum allowed value 2147483647

So how do i fix this to allow it be sent into mysql using the pony orm and python.

Comment: What is the datatype of credit_card_number in the table? why are you choosing to hold a number as a string?

Comment: @AmyGrange The string value for `credit_card_number` appears to be a JSON fragment.

Comment: i tried using int and it could not hold it. it's a json fragment

Comment: Ok - then I guess my next question is.. why are you storing a json fragment? is there some requirement we are unaware of?

Comment: I have a similar problem currently, where I try to save large IDs. The column in the database is defined as BIGINT. When I try to transfer the value from one table to another, the same error message for me occurs. It seems as if pony ORM cheks this size (because it is defined as int) and raises an error, even though the db behind it could handle the size. Is there a way to define 8 byte integers?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a long integer column type for the `credit_card_number` field.  On many databases (including MySQL, SQL Server, and Postgres), this would be a `BIGINT` type column.

Answer (score 0):

a conversion is only necessary, if you need to manipulate the json data and don't want to use the given database tools or build your own.

the extracting of json data isn't that hard, so you keep the json format.

python can hanlde long very well

```
Credit_Card_number = int
Credit_Card_number = 2221597849919620
print(Credit_Card_number)
print(type(Credit_Card_number))
```

results in

```
2221597849919620
<class 'int'>
```

so the line

```
Credit_Card_number = Required(int)
```

reduce the possible numbers.

simply don't use it and perform a check with `int(2221597849919620)`

Comment: i'm keeping the json format. i just need a way to take out the large number without an error.

Comment: you don't need to do anything in python 3 int behaves like long see my answer